# error while installing ccny_rgbd_tools

Tags: ros, kinect, visual-odometry, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I can't install ccny_rgbd_tools using the instructions that the README provides, the compiler always shows me the following message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:83 (add_executable):
Cannot find source file:

  apps/global_cloud_align.cpp

Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx


[rosmake-2] Finished <<< lib_rgbdtools [FAIL] [ 0.43 seconds ]
```

I don't have any idea where that file could be. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance, Raul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61535/error-while-installing-ccny_rgbd_tools/) by [RaulPL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3505/raulpl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-04-26**:
Where did you get the ccny_rgbd_tools from?  github?

**Comment by [RaulPL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3505/raulpl/) on 2013-04-26**:
Yes, the problem is already solved: https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/issues/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a bug which should now be fixed in master.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3